# HTTP Request/Response PHP

Tags: http, request, response

When a client/browser sends request to web server , then how server identifies to which client to send the response.I am aware of the request/response headers used by the web server to identify the request.But i am not able to clearly plot the information.

Can any one help me explore this topic in more details from request to response process.Like when client sends an request what are the parameters sent by the client to the server and what server sends back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in to standard TCP/IP and the HTTP protocol.

Google "Http made easy"

Answer (score 0):

for windows download wireshark (its free) and you can look what your client sends and what your server receives. On the linux machine check the tcpdump command.